# Не понятные мне ошибки при использовании TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

При компиляции любой прошраммы с использованием TensorFlow Появляются следующие ошибки:

```
2024-01-08 01:32:41.532196: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2024-01-08 01:32:41.532250: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2024-01-08 01:32:41.533249: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-01-08 01:32:41.539377: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-01-08 01:32:42.413888: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-01-08 01:32:42.985606: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:901] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
У нас есть GPU
2024-01-08 01:32:43.126429: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:901] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-01-08 01:32:43.126709: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:901] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Код:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if len(physical_devices) > 0:
    print("У нас есть GPU")
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
else:
    print("Извините, для вас нет GPU...")
```

Answer (score 0):

Аналогичная проблема на github tensorflow. Попробуйте выполнить [инструкцию](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/62075#issuecomment-1865242909)

Comment: Не помогло ошибки остались на месте